# Mysql partition - How to do list partitioning of a table that contains unique column?

Tags: mysql, database, partitioning, database-partitioning

I am doing mysql list partitioning. my table data is as below

```
----------------------------------------
id | unique_token | city | student_name |
----------------------------------------
1  | xyz          |mumbai| sanjay       |
-----------------------------------------
2  | abc          |mumbai| vijay        |
----------------------------------------
3  | def          | pune | ajay         |
----------------------------------------
```

In the above table `unique_token` column has a unique key and i want to do list partitioning with city column. As per mysql documentation every partition column must be part of every unique key of a table and hence in order to do list partitioning with city column i have to create new unique key as `unique_key(unique_token,city)`.

Now the issue is that unique_token column should be unique and if i insert two rows in the table as `('xyz','banglore') and ('xyz','pune')` then these rows will be inserted into the table but then unique_token column won't be unique at all.

I want to know how to do list partitioning on this table without having duplicate data in unique_token column??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are limitations in MySQL's `PARTITION` implementation.  In particular, no `FOREIGN KEYs` and no `UNIQUE` keys unless they happen to include the "partition key".  These limitation exist because of the unacceptable cost of implementing them.  This, in turn, is caused by each partition being essentially a separate 'table', with its own indexes.  There is no "index" that spans the entire set of partitions.  Such a 'global index' would make FKs and `UNIQUE` keys viable and efficient.  This *may* come in version 5.8.

Meanwhile, let me change your question from "*How* to do `LIST` partitioning..." to "*Why* do `LIST` partitioning at all?".  I know of no utility -- not performance, not convenience, not anything else, for `PARTITION BY LIST`.  If you have a reason for wanting to do it, *please* explain.  I would be happy to change my rather negative attitude toward partitioning.  (I know of *only 4* use cases for `PARTITION BY RANGE`, but that is another topic.)

Comment: What are other alternative solutions for this problem.

Comment: What is the _original_ problem?  The 'unique' restriction was a bump on the road.  What led you to consider partitioning?

Comment: In future my table will have around 10 billions(may be more than this) of data and searching for a particualr record from this 10 billions of data will take time hence  i choose partitioning .I thought if i did list partitioning by "city" column then searching for a particular student by name in particular "city" will give me faster response.

Comment: It won't be faster.  With partitioning, the query has to pick the right partition, then drill down a BTree.  This is essentially no faster than simply drilling down a BTree (as without partitioning), even though the BTree might be 4 levels versus 5.  [More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).

Answer (score 0):

Better to give composite primary key for (unique_token and city) columns

> alter table table_name add constraint constraint_name primary
>      key(unique_token and city).

Comment: This will not work because it will still add ('xyz','banglore') and ('xyz','pune')   rows in the table and therefore there will be duplicate values for unique_token column.